# How to make Mathematica substitute exact numerical values of (derivatives) 2F1

Tags: numerical-value, special-functions

I have a long output that contains Taylor expansion of some function. Some of the coefficients are combinations of the (derivatives of) 2F1 at nice integer values of the coefficients. I can see that all of them are zero or simple integers. For example, the following combination is zero 
$$\, {}_2F_1^{(0,0,1,0)}(2,2,1,0)+\, {}_2F_1^{(0,0,2,0)}(2,2,1,0)$$
when evaluated numerically. Is there any way to make Mathematica recognise this fact? There are many other rational numbers in the expression and applying 'N' to it would be unfortunate.

Comment: In this particular case `Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2, c, 0]` evaluates to a constant, which has zero derivative. This might not be the case for other combinations though. You can also use `FunctionExpand` (before derivative but after inserting the constants) to get a simpler representation in some cases. I think the main point is inserting the constants (except the one you want to derive) before doing the derivative to have abetter chance that Mathematica substitutes a simpler expression.

Comment: Only recently have there been usable [closed forms for parameter derivatives of the Gauss hypergeometric function](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/39/395208). Unfortunately, *Mathematica* is not yet aware of these closed forms.

Answer (score 1):

For these particular 2F1's you can use

```
X /. Derivative[0, 0, dc_, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][a_, b_, c_, z_] :> 
    (D[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, cc, z], {cc, dc}] /. cc -> c)
```

to simplify (assuming that your expression is stored in X).